# Grouping a many relationship in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, grouping

I've got the following code:

```
var preGroup =                
    from l in e.WorkOrderRequests
    join w in e.WorkOrders on l.WorkOrderRequestKey equals w.WorkOrderRequestKey into lw                
    from l2 in lw.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { l.WorkOrderRequestStatusKey, 
                 l.WorkOrderRequest_Status.Status, 
                 w.Property.Address.StateKey,
                 w.Property.Address.MetroKey };
```

The relationship structure is that a Work Order Request can have many Work Orders, so it is a 1 to many relationship.  I want to do a select so that each work order request will show up for as many times as there are work orders attached to it.  But also it still should appear if there are no work orders attached.  So a left outer join makes sense. The select above doesn't work, but that shows the data that I want to select.  I need to then group this data:

```
var workOrderRequests = 
    (from l in preGroup.ToList()
     group l by new { l.WorkOrderRequestStatusKey, l.Status, l.StateKey, l.MetroKey } into g
     select new DashboardView
     {
         StatusKey = g.Key.WorkOrderRequestStatusKey,
         StatusName = g.Key.Status,
         StateKey = g.Key.StateKey,
         MetroKey = g.Key.MetroKey,
         Count = g.Count()
     });
```

I can't get to the grouping because my `preGroup` query is not working.  I have been able to accomplish this for other things, but those are all 1 to 1 relationships.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I don't get it, why not just select from the `WorkOrderRequests` and include `WorkOrder`

Comment: Well I see I messed up, and if I just change the w. to l2. in the select statement, then it will work.  However, performance is much much worse than my previous solution.  Perhaps I am going about this the wrong way?